# AutoFilter on multiple criteria (array of strings) isn't returning properly

Tags: excel, vba

I've turned my csv files into macro-enabled sheets to use the macro I wrote to filter a page returning any rows that have a column match with any string in the criteria array. When running it on multiple files, it only returns for a couple of strings in the array. There's no matches for any of the array values in the 200k rows I have for that file. However, if I take the first string and manually filter that same file,  I get 100+ matches. Is there something wrong with the function?

(I took out the "_" line breaks because they don't line up in SO.)

```
Here's the function:

Sub filter_child_accounts()

ActiveSheet.Range("A1:FW1").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=Array(  "string1", "string2",
  "string3", "string4", "string5", "string6", "string7", "string8", ..., "stringN"), _ Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

There's about 100 strings in the array, so I thought maybe it was too much. There's no error returned, just a blank sheet except for the headers, but I know there's at least 100+ matches for the first string in the criteria array. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Works for me with just A1:FW1

Comment: I had read that the range was supposed to include just the headers, but I just changed it to include everything and it still shows up as blank.

Comment: Perhaps there's more code not shown which might be affecting the outcome?

Comment: That function is exactly as how it's written, just with the strings having their actual value. Do I need to include something else after the " Operator:=xlFilterValues." Is it just not showing the result?

Comment: What does your data actually look like - are the strings to match on unusually long for example?

Comment: they all have this form "zcrm_3485041111164136129" all with the same number of digits after the first 5 characters.

Comment: Still working for me with values like that...

Comment: Using the above, or the loop mentioned in your answer?

Comment: Using both the loop and the second approach I just added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for me to filter on 100 values:

```vb
Sub filter_child_accounts()
    
    Dim i As Long, arr(1 To 100),arr2
    
    For i = 1 To 100
        arr(i) = "blah" & i
    Next i

    If ws.FilterMode Then ws.ShowAllData 'remove any current filter
    
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:J1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues

    'Alternative approach picking the array directly from a range on another sheet
    arr2 = Application.Transpose(Sheets("Vals").Range("A1:A100").Value)
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:J1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=arr2, Operator:=xlFilterValues


End Sub
```

Data table has "blah1", "blah2" etc in ColA

Comment: I'll try this and replace "blah" with cell references to the workbook I'm holding the string values in and the iterator variable i.

Comment: If you have the values in a range then maybe look into using Advanced Filter?

Comment: Added a second approach which uses an array read directly from another worksheet.

Comment: I tried the second approach after adding another sheet to the excel file I'm testing on. It looks like this:

ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

    arr2 = Application.Transpose(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A110").Value)
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:FV1").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=arr2, Operator:=xlFilterValues

It throws a 'object variable or with block variable not set' error. Does that sheet need to be in another workbook?

Comment: I tried adding Dim arr2(108) before the array initialization but it said "can't set to an array."

Comment: @jmath412 change this line Criteria1:=arr to this Criteria1:=Array(arr)

Comment: I get the same 'object variable or With block variable not set.' Do I still need to be using the for loop for the alternative approach?

Comment: @jmath412 With `ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData` there has to be a filter on the sheet to start. Also Field:=8 applies filter to column H is that the correct column ?

Comment: Ahh, everywhere else, not for the showalldata, it's saying  not to have a filter. Adding that did it. Thank you so much, this is going to save me an insane amount of time extracting data!

Comment: @CDP1802 - thanks   Edited in a fix for the "no current filter" case.